# Package init and refresh problems

Tags: init-file, package, list-packages

Due to unknown reason(s), the package manager in my Emacs 25.3 cannot refresh properly anymore: whenever I try to do `M-x list-packages` it throws an error:

> error in process filter: package-read-archive-contents: Wrong type
>   argument: listp, <!DOCTYPE

And when I debug it using `emacs --debug-init`, it shows:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument listp <!DOCTYPE)
  package--read-archive-file("archives/sc/archive-contents")
  package-read-archive-contents("sc")
  package-read-all-archive-contents()
  package-initialize()
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*> nil "/Users/cya/.emacs" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 917
  load-with-code-conversion("/Users/cya/.emacs" "/Users/cya/.emacs" t t)
  load("~/.emacs" t t)
  #[0 "\205\266 \306=\203\307\310Q\202? \311=\204\307\312Q\202?\313\307\314\315#\203*\316\202?\313\307\314\317#\203>\320\321\322!D\nB\323\202?\316\324\325\324\211#\210\324=\203e\326\327\330\307\331Q!\"\325\324\211#\210\324=\203d\210\203\247\332!\333\232\203\247\334!\211\335P\336!\203\201\211\202\214\336!\203\213\202\214\314\262\203\245\337\"\203\243\340\341#\210\342\343!\210\266\f?\205\264\314\325\344\324\211#)\262\207" [init-file-user system-type delayed-warnings-list user-init-file inhibit-default-init inhibit-startup-screen ms-dos "~" "/_emacs" windows-nt "/.emacs" directory-files nil "^\\.emacs\\(\\.elc?\\)?$" "~/.emacs" "^_emacs\\(\\.elc?\\)?$" initialization format-message "`_emacs' init file is deprecated, please use `.emacs'" "~/_emacs" t load expand-file-name "init" file-name-as-directory "/.emacs.d" file-name-extension "elc" file-name-sans-extension ".el" file-exists-p file-newer-than-file-p message "Warning: %s is newer than %s" sit-for 1 "default"] 7]()
  command-line()
  normal-top-level()
```

So apparently the error is associated with `archives/sc/archive-contents` file, and according to [this question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/19576/how-to-fix-this-startup-package-initialization-problem), deleting the file should fix the problem when Emacs refreshes the packages again. Unfortunately deleting it and refresh the packages bring back the same error `error in process filter: package-read-archive-contents: Wrong type argument: listp, &lt;!DOCTYPE`

And going into the `archives/sc/archive-contents` file, it seems to show a lot of irrelevant stuff, e.g.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <html> <head> <meta charset="utf-8" /> <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" /><script type="text/javascript">/* <![CDATA[ */
accConf = {"events":{"endpointPaths":["/a8f4d8cd95e164917035b64b867a45dd"]}};
/* ]]> */</script>
 <meta name="msapplication-starturl" content="https://www.onet.pl/"/> <meta name="msapplication-task" content="name=Wiadomości;action-uri=http://wiadomosci.onet.pl/;icon-uri=https://ocdn.eu/paas-static/template-engine/5fd508316edf96eb0c840a8116572c42/faviconn2.ico"/> <meta name="msapplication-task" content="name=Biznes;action-uri=http://biznes.onet.pl/;icon-uri=https://ocdn.eu/paas-static/template-engine/5fd508316edf96eb0c840a8116572c42/faviconn.ico"/> <meta name="msapplication-task" content="name=Sport;action-uri=http://sport.onet.pl/;icon-uri=https://ocdn.eu/paas-static/template-engine/5fd508316edf96eb0c840a8116572c42/faviconn.ico"/> <meta name="msapplication-task" content="name=Film;action-uri=http://film.onet.pl/;icon-uri=https://ocdn.eu/paas-static/template-engine/5fd508316edf96eb0c840a8116572c42/faviconn.ico"/> <meta name="msapplication-task" content="name=Muzyka;action-uri=http://muzyka.onet.pl/;icon-uri=https://ocdn.eu/paas-static/template-engine/5fd508316edf96eb0c840a8116572c42/faviconn.ico"/> <meta name="msapplication-task" content="name=VOD;action-uri=https://vod.pl/;icon-uri=https://ocdn.eu/paas-static/template-engine/5fd508316edf96eb0c840a8116572c42/faviconn.ico"/> <meta name="description" content="Onet: codzienne źródło informacji milionów Polaków - wiadomości z kraju i ze świata 24/7, pogoda, sport, biznes, moto, rozrywka. Bądź na bieżąco z Onet!"/> <meta property="og:image" content="https://ocdn.eu/images/pulscms/OWU7MDA_/20ec3038d7c7d1637e04da3395de954d.png">  <meta name="referrer" content="origin"> <meta name="staticr-list" content="https://www.onet.pl/staticurls.txt"> <meta name="viewport" content="width=1024"> <!-- config vars --> <meta name="onet-appconfig" data-config='{"variantName":"www.onet.pl::HTTPS_PROD1","pipisenabled":0,"recommender":3}'> <!-- // config vars -->  <meta name="onet-sgexpconfig" data-expenabled='1'> <meta name="onet-o24editor" data-autoplay='1'>  <!-- // yt boo config -->   <meta name="onet-o24it" data-autoplay="100">   <meta name="dreamlab-test" data-percentvalue="0">   <meta name="onet-push" data-percentvalue="100">  <title>Onet – Jesteś na bieżąco</title>   <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json" /> <link rel="canonical" href="https://www.onet.pl" /> <link rel="alternate" media="only screen and (max-width: 768px)" href="https://m.onet.pl" /> <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="https://ocdn.eu" /> <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="https://lib.onet.pl" /> <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="https://csr.onet.pl" /> <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="https://kropka.onet.pl" /> <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="https://google-analytics.com" /> <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="https://securepubads.g.doubleclick.net" /> <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" /> <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" /> <link rel="shortcut icon" href="https://ocdn.eu/paas-static/template-engine/5fd508316edf96eb0c840a8116572c42/faviconn.ico" type="image/x-icon" /> <!--^M
        <link href="https://ocdn.eu/paas-static/template-engine/5fd508316edf96eb0c840a8116572c42/build/nsg2017.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" /> --> <style type="text/css"> @font-face {font-family: 'Fira Sans'; font-style: normal; font-weight: 400; src: local('Fira Sans Regular'), local('FiraSans-Regular'), url(https://ocdn.eu/onetmobilemainpage/firafonts/p05/FiraSans-Regular.woff) format('woff');}^M
            @font-face {font-family: 'Fira Sans'; font-style: normal; font-weight: 500; src: local('Fira Sans Medium'), local('FiraSans-Medium'), url(https://ocdn.eu/onetmobilemainpage/firafonts/p05/FiraSans-Medium.woff) format('woff');}^M
```

Any suggestion what may cause the error and how to fix it?

Comment: remove the directory `~/emacs.d/elpa` and try again, you'd better back it up.